# Collecting statistics from a JasperReports Table?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm using the JasperReports table component and I need to do the following. Each row in the table is a number from the dataset. I need to display the average number of all rows in the column footer. How can I do this in the `<textFieldExpression>` of the `jr:columnFooter`?